# Persist data as an (unordered) set in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB with node.js. Is it possible to persist data as an (unordered) set in MongoDB directly? Or do I have to either

- persist them as an array and transform it into a set in JavaScript

or

- persist them as an object in the form of `{entry1: true, entry2: true, ...}`

If I have to do it in either of the two ways above, which one is more efficient? Considering I need to add/remove items frequently, but rarely need to re-assign the whole set/array.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate an array as a set in MongoDB... relevant operators include:

- [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_addToSet) -  The $addToSet operator adds a value to an array only if the value is not in the array already.
- [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_push) - The $push operator appends a specified value to an array.
- [$pop](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_pop) - The $pop operator removes the first or last element of an array.
- [$pull](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_pull) - The $pull operator removes all instances of a value from an existing array.
- [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_elemMatch) - The $elemMatch operator matches more than one component within an array element.

Comment: I am wondering how efficient `$addToSet` compared with setting a value on a true hash set. Also, in the code, it is not efficient to remove a particular value from an array.